# Regexp Pattern.MULTILINE problem

Tags: java, regex

I don't understand why if I use:

```
boolean found = Pattern.compile("^\\d", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher("dfg\n5t").find();
```

, it returns true.

But If I use:

```
// taken from two input field with the same above values!!!
String rx = txt_rx.getText();
String ch = txt_ch.getText();

boolean found = Pattern.compile(rx, Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(ch).find();
```

, it returns false.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, could you post full source code where is clear where `rx` and `ch` are taken.

Comment: i suggest printing `rx`, `ch` to stdout (or inspecting in a debugger). Simply they must be sth different that you think they are.

Comment: The string returned by getText are the same as string literals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that strings returned by `getText()` are the same as string literals, but they shouldn't be the same!

`\\` and `\n` are special escape sequences which are interpreted (as `\` and newline respectively) in string literals only. If you want to read the same strings  as you get after interpretation of string literals from the text fields, you should enter them as `^\d` and

```
dfg
5t
```

respectively. You need a mulitline text field to enter the latter value (`JTextArea` in Swing).